# Devo tomar alguma ação em relação ao Heartbleed?

Tags: segurança, openssl

Como desenvolvedor, tenho que tomar alguma ação em relação ao [Heartbleed](http://heartbleed.com/)? Sendo um problema no OpenSSL, acredito que seja mais do âmbito de webmasters, administradores de servidores, etc. Mas não estou seguro se é só isso mesmo (atualizar o OpenSSL e trocar todos os certificados e senhas) ou se tem mais alguma ação específica a ser tomada, ou algum detalhe que teríamos que prestar atenção.

Contextualizando, para quem não está ciente do problema: foi identificado recentemente um bug no OpenSSL que permitia ao atacante acessar regiões de memória arbitrárias no servidor, tudo isso sem a necessidade de autenticação e sem deixar rastro. Certificados, chaves privadas, senhas, dados pessoais, nada estaria seguro. Ele está sendo descrito como ["a pior falha de segurança da história da Internet"](http://www.techtudo.com.br/noticias/noticia/2014/04/heartbleed-afeta-yahoo-mail-e-tumblr-especialista-sugere-troca-de-senha.html), ["numa escala de 1 a 10, isso é um 11"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2014/04/heartbleed.html), etc. No site security.SE, a tag `heartbleed`, criada ontem (2014-04-08), [já tem quase 50 perguntas](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heartbleed). Tudo isso já dá uma ideia das dimensões dessa vulnerabilidade, e por que ela merece uma atenção especial nesse momento.

Comment: Já que ninguém responde, vou pelo menos comentar meu ponto de vista. Pelo que li sobre o bug, não é necessária uma ação específica por parte do desenvolvedor e sim pelo administrador da rede ou da infraestrutura de serviços. Entretanto, a informação deve ser de conhecimento de todos os que são afetados pela falha num negócio (neste caso, até o presidente), os quais devem demandar a correção imediata. Na verdade, em muitos casos será o próprio desenvolvedor a resolver o problema, se ele for o tipo de profissional que veste vários chapéus no trabalho e tem as permissões necessárias.

Comment: Melhor "explicação visual" do bug: http://xkcd.com/1354/

Comment: Curiosidade: [Heartbleed **pode** não permitir, de fato, o acesso às chaves privadas.](http://blog.cloudflare.com/answering-the-critical-question-can-you-get-private-ssl-keys-using-heartbleed)

Comment: @GuilhermeAgostinelli : dependendo se vc usa o apache, ngix... Em geral, com segurança, é melhor pecar pela precaução.

Comment: Relacionadas: [What should a website operator do about the Heartbleed OpenSSL exploit?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/55076), [Is Stack Exchange safe from Heartbleed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228758/185667) e [What versions of OS X are affected by Heartbleed?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126916/21950)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Após a correção do bug e revogação dos certificados comprometidos eu exigiria uma troca de senha obrigatória de todos os usuários no primeiro login. Nesta ultima parte da troca de senha entra o trabalho do desenvolvedor.

Comment: Estou aceitando essa resposta, pois de fato parece que é só isso mesmo. Se surgirem informações adicionais, eu revejo (mas pelo tempo passado e pela progressão dos acontecimentos, creio que não vai ter novidade não...)

Answer (score 2):

A única ação necessária é testar a(s) sua(s) aplicação(ões) com a versão corrigida da biblioteca OpenSSL para garantir que elas funcionem, para que os webmasters e administradores de servidores não tenham problemas na hora de atualizar a biblioteca.

Comment: A maioria das aplicações não interage diretamente com o OpenSSL, por ser algo de mais baixo nível, mas de todo modo é uma ótima recomendação! Boa pra agilizar a migração, evitar surpresas...

Comment: Verdade @mgibsonbr, geralmente elas interagem com o servidor e runtime/vm que por sua vez interagem com a OpenSSL, por isso prefiro considerar a troca da biblioteca como uma atualização do servidor/runtime/vm e agir de de acordo.